# Shared folders with GitLab Docker runners

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-volume

Here's my configuration:

I'm using docker gitlab-runners to start docker-compose with the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - run

# Official docker compose image.
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.23.2 # update tag to whatever version you want to use.
  entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]

services: # is that really necessary? behavior seems the same with or without
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker version
  - docker-compose version

run_compose:
  stage: run
  script:
    - mkdir /c
    - touch /c/__CREATED_FROM_RUNNER__
    - docker-compose down -v
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up
    - ls -l /c
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /c/*
```

The `docker-compose.yml` used in the previous script version looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  snitch:
    image: snitch:latest
    environment:
      - PROGRAM_NAME=${PROGRAM_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /c:/caps

  xtools:
    image: xtools:latest
    environment:
      - PROGRAM_NAME=${PROGRAM_NAME}
```

The "snitch" container is writing files to the `/caps` directory. I assumed that the volume section meant that the `/c` directory in the runner container would receive the files, and that they would be collected as artifacts.

The actual behavior is that the `/c` directory of the container is empty (only the file created by the touch command in the .gitlab-ci.yml is present), but there's a `/c` directory created on the *physical machine of the runner* with the files inside it (!), but without the `__CREATED_FROM_RUNNER__` file.

Any insights about what's happening would be greatly appreciated. Plus, how can I retrieve the created files as artifacts?